# Calculate the estimated page load time

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Is it possible using jQuery/Javascript to calculate the estimated load time of a page?

I've tried the following which I found somewhere online but the time increments on each reload by 200 and when it gets to 6000 it resets back to 0

```
var perfData = window.performance.timing,
    EstimatedTime = -(perfData.loadEventEnd - perfData.navigationStart),
    time = parseInt((EstimatedTime/1000)%60)*100;

if (time >= 700) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        // Do something
    });
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

I wanted it to use a preloader if the estimated page load time was 700ms or more.

Comment: Load a 100kb image, measure the time it takes to load and you can get the whole page load time (in avergage) `toLoad/100kb * timeItTook`

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this programmatically? I ask as you can see this information in the console of most browsers.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Simply because page speeds for different people will vary so if someone has a super fast download speed will see the preloader for a split second which would look odd and vise versa

Comment: @JonasW. content is going to be dynamic and if I use the time it took for the previous load it could vary substantially to the current load time

Answer (score 2):

The [performance Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) will work if well used. It is browser compatible.

Now, the behavior you describe make me confident you just do not use it well.

The *«time increments on each reload by 200»* just indicates that `perfData.loadEventEnd` equals zero. Then your calculation just means nothing. You only have the `perfData.navigationStart`, which is the time in Unix integer.

Now, I would completely remove the maths you have for `time`. The `EstimatedTime` already is in milliseconds.

Then, the script should read the `timing` attribute once the page has fully loaded. Else, the `perfData.loadEventEnd` will be zero for sure.

So in the `load` event handler, use `setTimeout()` to make sure the script will execute AFTER the `load` event has ended.

```
var loadTime = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    var perfData = window.performance.timing;
    var EstimatedTime = (perfData.loadEventEnd - perfData.navigationStart);

    if(EstimatedTime>700){
      // Something for load time more than 700 ms
    }else{
      // Something for faster load time
    }
  },10);  // Executes 10 ms after load has ended
};
```

And in the markup:

```
<body onload="loadTime();">
```

Try to play with it in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/LOaQYp?editors=1111).

Your issue reproduced is in this other [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/zPbWqN?editors=1111).

Comment: True, but this will only return a correct value if it's run after the page load which is great but I don't know how I could implement this to get the time before the page load finishes to determine if the preloader would be needed. I'll still up vote you in this case since it helped me understand the performance API better.

Comment: I think you just can't take that measurement *before*... For each page. But if you do it on your landing page once, you will be able to deduct a *speed* for all the other pages. I would place that measurement in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for the other pages, where the data will be usable before `load` has finished.

Comment: Some other taughts: **1)** That measurement will be efficient on ***first*** load. Second load probably will use caching to speed-up load time, so this value should lower. **2)** I would measure the load time on one particular image, instead of the `body`... Say your logo in the header. So that measument can be made on any of your pages. **3)** If your logo is too small... Use an hidden BIG image!! **4)** And finally, if the value already is in localStorage, just don't update it... Keep the first measurement. ;)

Comment: You can use localStorage to know if a particular page already was loaded too... So you may decide not to show the *preloader* (which I suppose is a rotating gif) even if load time is high. Or take a second measurement in that case... But again, just **keep** the initial measurement!

Comment: Hmm ok thanks, I'll have a more in depth look into localStorage and I'll see if I can implement something like what you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

What is the end of page load? `window.onload`?

```
var first= new Date();

$(window).load(function() {
   $('body').html(new Date() - first);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this wasn't what I meant, I want to estimate how long the page will take to be loaded before it finishes loading. So if it estimates the page load time would be 2.3 seconds I would want it to do something but if it estimated it was going to be 400 milliseconds then do something else